# gulp sass relative paths

Tags: sass, gulp

sass gives an error message

```
Error: File to import not found or unreadable: helpers/mixins.scss
   Parent style sheet: .../temp/styles/all.scss
    on line 1 of temp/styles/all.scss
>> @import 'helpers/mixins.scss';
   ^
```

at this point, the code looks like

```
@import 'helpers/mixins.scss';
@import 'helpers/variables.scss';
@import 'helpers/fonts.scss';
@import '../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';
@import '../../node_modules/fotorama/fotorama.css';

.navbar {
  @extend navbar-light;
  @extend bg-faded;
}
```

gulp task looks like this

```
var blocks = 'app/blocks/**/*.scss';

gulp.task('styles', () => (
gulp.src(['app/styles/app.scss', blocks])
    .pipe(concat('all.scss'))
    .pipe(sass({
        errLogToConsole: true,
        indentedSyntax: false
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('temp/styles'))
));
```

How to solve this problem?
how to make galp correctly understand the way?

Answer (score 1):

In your gulp file you can declare sass paths, eg.

```
var sassPaths = [
  'node_modules/bootstrap/scss',
  'node_modules/fotorama'
];
```

These are relative to your gulp file.

Then set include paths inside your list of sass arguments

```
.pipe(sass({
    errLogToConsole: true,
    indentedSyntax: false,
    includePaths: sassPaths
}))
```

Then in your sass make sure your imports are either relaitve to the parent sass file or relative to one of the include paths.

Comment: the problem isn't the import path, it's the compiler. a sass compiler should handle import statements. never had any issues with this using the sass compiler  for visual studio, just saying

Comment: There's no real problem though is there? This is in the docs about how to do it and it works :)